# which nova-compute libvirt's images_type better for me, raw or qcow2, glance image's disk_format is raw

Tags: image, openstack, disk

We want to add some compute nodes which will support create instances with *local disk*, and I have no idea how to define the `images_type` of instances, but one point, we pursue the high disk **I/O** performance.

- **glance image info**, this is settled by our team and could not change.

| Field | Value |
| --- | --- |
| container_format | bare |
| disk_format | raw |

- **nova-compute/nova.conf**, which type would I choose and why ?

```
[libvirt]
#images_type = qcow2
#images_type = raw
```

Comment: The image-type of glance is totally independent from the nova image-type, because when creating a VM nova converts the image within the compute-host. Where I work we don't use the local storage of nova certain reasons, so I'm not totally familiar with these 2 offered types. So I can not give you some experiences from myself, but I heard from others, that the qcow2-type has a low I/O performance for a local storage, that's why in my opinion you should prefer the raw-type, when you want performance. In raw-format you have no compression, so this would be much bigger on disc then qcow2.

Comment: @Tobias THX, I will try it.