# how openstack resize instance with raw format's local disk

Tags: resize, local, openstack, openstack-nova, raw

Instance using local disk, the configure file: **nova-compute/nova.conf**

```
[libvirt]
images_type = qcow2
```

execute `openstack server resize` works well.

but when using `raw`

```
[libvirt]
images_type = raw
```

the instance console get:

[image]

Is there any method to resize the raw format local disk instance successful ? THX

Comment: IIUC this has nothing to do with the `resize` operation. `openstack server resize` just applies a different flavor (more RAM, VCPU etc.) to the same disk image. If your base image is in qcow format you should not change it to raw and the other way around. If you want to reformat an image you should download it `openstack image save...` and then use `qemu-img convert ...` to use a different format and then upload it back to glance with the appropriate format. But then you'll have two different images in your glance store. If I misunderstood your question please clarify.

Comment: @eblock it's not about image's format, it's only the instance format. no matter about the `image(glance)`'s format, the instance format only dependent on `[libvirt]`'s `image_type`.

Comment: The instance format is the image format, an instance is launched from a base image, so those are definitely linked. I'm still not sure what you're trying to achieve by changing the libvirt image_type.

Comment: Check from this: "https://docs.openstack.org/nova/latest/configuration/config.html#libvirt.images_type" or the first comment or this "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68226802/which-nova-compute-libvirts-images-type-better-for-me-raw-or-qcow2-glance-ima" .

Comment: Now I understand. If you enable debug logs for nova-compute you should see the exact command and maybe can reproduce manually what’s going wrong. Although since the instance is started successfully there’s nothing going wrong from openstack point of view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to set one additional configuration option [1] to enable resize to work with the `raw` image backend:

```
[DEFAULT]
use_cow_images = False

[libvirt]
images_type = raw
```

When `use_cow_images = True` the libvirt driver will convert `raw` images to `qcow2` when finishing resizes or cold migrations [2][3]. This will break the instance trying to come back up after the resize because the libvirt driver will generate instance XML indicating disk format `raw`while the disk file image has actually been converted to `qcow2`. The mismatch results in an un-bootable instance.

Based on this, I think if you want to use `raw` images, you must also configure:

```
[DEFAULT]
use_cow_images = False
```

to avoid the image format conversion.

[1] https://docs.openstack.org/nova/latest/configuration/config.html#DEFAULT.use_cow_images

[2] https://opendev.org/openstack/nova/commit/61b34ed

[3] https://opendev.org/openstack/nova/commit/7b15ed3

Comment: It works! That's what I want, thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

In my test, there is one stupid method but it works:

- 1, `openstack server stop original_instance` and `openstack server remove port original_instance original_port`.
- 2, `openstack image create` with the original instance's **raw** format's **disk** file (image named **disk_img** in the below).
- 3, `openstack server create new_instance --image **disk_img**` with `original_port` and `new_flavor`(disk capability can't smaller than original).